# Couple newbie questions regarding the openJS grid

Tags: php, mysql, grid

i am playing with the openJS grid. Being through all the videos, however still stuck. I am using the latest OpenJS Grid 2.1.5. Couple questions here:

1. When i used the basic setup example, with the save and delete set to true, i don't see either one show up in the grid. What am i missing?
2. How do i change the theme? The example just have the white background theme. I want to change it to that similar to the video tutorial dark color theme. How do i do that?
3. How do i select rows, highlight the column? I click the column, it just does the sorting. Click cell, it won't select the row nor put it on the top as shown in the video.

Thanks,

Wei,

The html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../grid.css" title="openJsGrid"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script src="../root.js"></script>
    <script src="../grid.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".purchases").grid();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Insider Purphases</h2>
    <table class="grid purchases" action="insider.php">
      <tr>
        <th col="Insider">Insider Name</th>
        <th col="Company">Company</th>
        <th col="Symbol">Symbol</th>
        <th col="Amount">Amount</th>
        <th col="Relationship">Relationship</th>
        <th col="Date">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The php file

```
<?php
// connect to db
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("insidertrades");

// require our class
require_once("../grid.php");

// load our grid with a table
$grid = new Grid("purchases", array(
    "save"=>true,
    "delete"=>true
));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, at least turned the editing flag in the javascript bring back the "save" button which make sense.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".purchases").grid({
              editing:true
           });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

WHOA sorry I didn't see this till 10 months later. I didn't monitor stack for OpenJS Grid questions.

1) You need to turn features like save and delete on on both JS and PHP (This is for security, I promise it's a necessary evil)

2) CSS my friend. Just a little bit of CSS and you're good to go. The grid.css file is fully commented. I didn't make easy-switch themes this time around. No one was using those.

3) To highlight a column add a

```
$grid.on("cellClick", function(e,$cell) {
    $cell.closest(".col").find(".cell[data-row]").css("background","blue")
});
```

Just to give you an idea. Please update to 2.1.7 if you haven't already.

Thanks!